# Projects doesn't load in the android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 2.1.3.My emulator works perfectly, show inbuilt apps etc but does not show the projects I created.To check whether it was by a mistake that I made,I just ran a simple hello world app but still it does not show up on the emulator.

These messages come on the bottom panel under AVD:

**C:\Users\Chanaka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23_new**

**Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M**

**emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB**

**emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB**

**Hax is enabled**

**Hax ram_size 0x40000000**

**HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555**

These messages comes under App:

> 09/10 16:33:57: Launching app $ adb push
>   C:\Users\Chanaka\AndroidStudioProjects\Letstrythisone\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.letstrythisone
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5554'
>   not found

Error while Installing APK

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not show up on the emulator"? Can you run your app in the emulator?

Comment: No it doesn't show my app

Comment: What happens when you click the run button in Android Studio?

Comment: My emulator loads .First it shows the word "android" for a few minutes.After that it shows the home screen of the nexus 5x.Then when I click the menu button all preloaded apps like settings,camera,gallery comes but doesn't show the app I built.

Comment: I suggest starting the emulator from the AVID Manager. Wait for the launched to appear before running your app.

Comment: Can  you give me the instructions to do that?